# How to solve 'macOS Package Authoring Error'

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install a new version of macOS. The only option I have is mojave. Despite that , when I click continue (the very first step in the installation wizard) it takes some time and says "the request to recovery server timed out".

Using a macbook pro 13inch, 2018 built.

The log says, Package Authoring Error,

access to path " /tmp/com.apple.pkg.testing" requires

and similar errors.
I do have a proper, uninterrupted Internet connection.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Mac comes with a bunch of options, install new macos, update the current os, **reinstall the os that came with the laptop**. My solution was this,

`shift+options+cmd+r` on boot and it will reinstall the mac os that came along with the laptop.

Source : [apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)